# Flexbox - Content in card to be spaced evenly

Tags: css, flexbox

This is probably a really simple answer, but it's frustrating me. I have a flex container with 2 items side-by-side; there is an image for one, and content for the other side. In the content, it is centered both horizentally and vertically, but the content is stacked pretty tightly on top of each other (title, text, button). Is there a way to have them evenly spaced around the height of the card?

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#container-image>img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#container-image {
  flex: 1;
}

#container-content {
  flex: 2;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #34495e;
}
```

```html
HTML:

<section id="container">
  <div id="container-image">
    <img src="https://www.placecage.com/c/1500/2000" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div id="container-content">
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p>some text about this card</p>
    <a class="button">more...</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider another flexbox container for the text using column direction and then you can easily space them like you want:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#container-image>img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#container-image {
  flex: 1;
}

#container-content {
  flex: 2;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:space-evenly; /*you can also use space-between OR space-around*/
}

.button {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  align-self:center;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #34495e;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
  <div id="container-image">
    <img src="https://www.placecage.com/c/1500/2000" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div id="container-content">
    <h3>title</h3>
    <p>some text about this card</p>
    <a class="button">more...</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Is there any way to get that to work for IE11? Edit: fixed, needed to change the space-evenly, must be a bug using it with IE11.

Comment: @n1234 yes space-evenly is not supported by all the broswers ;) you can refer to this link : https://caniuse.com/#search=justify-content in the bottom of the known issues

Comment: I'm using a fallback of adding space-around before space-evenly. Seems to be working as expected. Thanks!